# How to split a triangle mesh by a closed curve in cgal?

Tags: mesh, image-segmentation, cgal

There is a closed curve on surface of my triangle mesh, I want to split the mesh into two parts by the curve, can it be done in `CGAL`?

I've checked [Corefinement and Boolean Operations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html) section, I don't think `clip`,`split` or `boolean operation` is the answer.